# FB.ui apprequests is not working on iFrame Tab

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm using facebook JS api and

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'apprequests',
  message: 'You should learn more about this awesome game.',
  data: 'tracking information for the user'
});
```

but its not working on tab , the pop-up stats to load and then automatically become hidden .

Comment: can you pls provide some more of your code?

Comment: <script>
function invite(){
       FB.ui({
       method: 'apprequests',
       message: 'this is the message'
       });
    }
</script>

<a href='#' onclick='invite()'>Invite Friends</a>

Answer (score 0):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/

You can only use iframe in facebook apps, probably also on tab pages.

Comment: facebook apps and tabs all are now on iFrame , you cant use the fbml.